# how do I enable WebGL?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm going to dive into browser game development and thus I need webGL but it does not work in any browser here on my Ubuntu. I'm using Chrome version 36.0.1985.125 and the result on `chrome://gpu` are as follows:
[image]

So I can't use webGL and it's pretty annoying. I googled and followed advices and enabled `Override software rendering list`:
[image]

but still have no luck. I tried `google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist` but with no effect. So how can I made this work?
Also everythyng work fine on chrome in windows and it also does not work here in ubuntu in Firefox 26. I installed latest NVIDIA drivers yesrterday but still no effect. What may cause problems?

Comment: Did you try: http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2009/10/26/how_to_enable_webgl_on_google_chrome.html ?

Comment: @alexander255, I tried `google-chrome --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist` but with no effect.

Comment: @SET That's odd... Can you install Chromium and check if the same happens (`chromium-browser --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist`) ?

Comment: @Salem, for some reasons I can't install it. Here is installation output - http://pastebin.com/E3KGdwye

Comment: @SET That's because 12.10 is no longer supported. See http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/33871

Comment: @Salem, well, at least I installed Chromium 25.0.1364.172 and webGL sites work exept they are extremely laggy and chrome://gpu/ still show `WebGL: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable`.

Comment: changed "Override software rendering list:" and it now work in chromium. How can I make it work in chrome. (also long time was wonderint about what is the difference between this wto browsers)

Comment: Difference is that Chrome is closes-source by Google and contains some proprietary extensions by Google (like a newer version of Flash Player) [ https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/ ]; while Chromium are only the open-sourced parts of Chrome compiled by Ubuntu devs [ http://www.chromium.org/Home & https://launchpad.net/chromium-browser ].